# Вывод переменных окружения Windows в файл .txt с форматированием

Tags: cmd, bat

Привет всем есть задание , вывести переменные окружения Windows в файл .txt чтобы данных отображались в нём в виде таблицы, сделать это нужно с помощью bat файла. Если мы делаем вывод в файл данные выглядят таким образом изначально: 
[image: переменные окружения не в табличном виде]

нужно привести к такому виду:
[image: в табличном виде]

но основная загвоздка в том что картинка №2 была сделана с помощью скрипта написанного в powershell , нужно же сделать такой же вывод как на 2 ой картинке но только с помощью batch(на котором пишутся bat файлы для windows), все кто может помочь в решении помогите пожалуйста я уже тонну информации перелопатил так и не смог сделать, если можете сделать за деньги то пишите цену.Всем спасибо за внимание.

Comment: попробуйте #9 - символ табуляции использовать.

Comment: Можно примитивнее сделать. Нарастить строку пробелам (да хоть +100 штук): **set "string=%string%                        "** А затем обрезать строку до фиксированной длины (хотя бы до 35): **set string=%string:~0,35%**

Answer (score 0):

Следующий комментиробанный `653805.bat` скрипт может помочь.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
:: вычислить максимальную длину 
set "_varLenMax=2"
for /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%G in ('set %~1 ^|findstr /V "^_"') do (
    set "_varName=%%G"
    call :strlen _varLen _varName
    rem отладочный вывод call echo %%_varLen%% %%_varName%%
    call :compareLen 
)


set "_separator=  "
for /L %%G in (1,1,%_varLenMax%) do call set "_separator= %%_separator%%"

:: (optional) header (Факультативный) заголовок
set "_varName=Name%_separator%"
call echo %%_varName:~0,%_varLenMax%%% Value
:: (optional) header separator (Факультативный) разделитель заголовки
set "_varName=----%_separator%"
call echo %%_varName:~0,%_varLenMax%%% -----

for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%G in ('set %~1 ^|findstr /V "^_"') do (
    set "_varName=%%G%_separator%"
    call echo %%_varName:~0,%_varLenMax%%% %%H
)

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:: похвала: jeb, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5841587/3439404
:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!%~2!#"
    set "len=0"
    for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
            set /a "len+=%%P"
            set "s=!s:~%%P!"
        )
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)

:compareLen
if %_varLen% GTR %_varLenMax% set /A "_varLenMax=_varLen"
goto :eof
```

[Кракозя́бры](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) в имени пользователья `USERNAME` и `USERPROFILE` происходят из разности набора символов в кодировках [`Windows-1251`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) и  [`CP-866`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP866)

```
d:\bat> chcp 866
Active code page: 866

d:\bat> >D:\bat\SU_ru\file653805.txt D:\bat\SU_ru\653805.bat x

d:\bat> type D:\bat\SU_ru\file653805.txt
Name               Value
----               -----
x32                C:\Windows\SysWOW64
xProgramFiles(x86) C:\Program Files (x86)
xrussian           Александр

d:\bat> chcp 1251
Active code page: 1251

d:\bat> type D:\bat\SU_ru\file653805.txt
Name               Value
----               -----
x32                C:\Windows\SysWOW64
xProgramFiles(x86) C:\Program Files (x86)
xrussian           Ђ«ҐЄб ­¤а

d:\bat> >D:\bat\SU_ru\file653805.txt D:\bat\SU_ru\653805.bat x

d:\bat> type D:\bat\SU_ru\file653805.txt
Name               Value
----               -----
x32                C:\Windows\SysWOW64
xProgramFiles(x86) C:\Program Files (x86)
xrussian           Александр

d:\bat> chcp 866
Active code page: 866

d:\bat> type D:\bat\SU_ru\file653805.txt
Name               Value
----               -----
x32                C:\Windows\SysWOW64
xProgramFiles(x86) C:\Program Files (x86)
xrussian           └ыхъёрэфЁ

d:\bat>
```